# excel macro copy and paste

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 sheets, sheet 1 has a cell with total price formula on it. I want to copy that cell on sheet 1 to sheet 2 column G2 going down every time I click on the macro (UPDATE button) with a new price total.

I have tried recording a macro but whenever I click the update button it paste the cell but with a  REF! error or a value 0.

can anyone help me.

thanks

```
range("b3").select
application.cutcopypaste=false
selection.copy
sheets("sheets2").select
range("b4").select
selection.insert shift:=xldown
```

Comment: Where is the code you have tried and where does it error?

Comment: i recorded the macro. this is the code for the recorded macro

Comment: code has been posted

Comment: Are you looking for something that would put it in the next blank row?

Comment: just tried the code in macro builder, but doesn't seem to work...

Comment: What didn't work? You are not being very clear

Comment: the code that I provided that you edited

Comment: Did you get an error? Did copy unexpectedly?

Comment: ok the code is alright, I have assigned it to a button but when it copies over  to sheet 2 the value is just 0 where it should be 104, there is a formula in the cell which is =sum(B1:B2)

Comment: Try `=Sum($B$1:$B1)`

Comment: tried that already but still ends up being 0 value instead of the total price

Comment: What formula gets pasted in the G column cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variant without copy

```
Sub test()
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value
End Sub
```

Variant with copy method

```
Sub test2()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
End Sub
```

Another one vatiant using copy method

```
Sub test3()
Sheets("Sheet1").[B3].Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest answer:

```
Sheets("Source Sheet Name").Range("B3").Copy
Sheets("Destination Sheet Name").Range("G" & Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Paste
```

Comment: @MatteoNNZ He always wants the copy cell to stay the same (reference formula)

Comment: also tried this code but gives error "object doesn't support this property or method"